# React native JSON to datatable

Tags: react-native

I need to fetch a JSON doc, and then populate a DataTable with the data from the JSON object. Fetching the data, etc... is straight forward, but handling the response and formatting inline with the datatable below is where I'm struggling;

```
state = {
    tableHead: ['Pos', '', 'P', 'W', 'D', 'L', 'GD', 'PTS'],
    tableData: [
      ['  1', 'Cheshire Futsal Club Men', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0', '  0'],
      ['  2', 'Derby Futsal Club Mens 1st Team', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0', '  0'],
      ['  3', 'Durham Palatinates First', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0', '  0'],
      ['  4', 'Loughborough Students Futsal Club Dev', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0', '  0'],
      ['  5', 'Sunderland University Team Sunderland', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0', '  0'],
      ['  6', 'University of Nottingham Futsal National', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0', '  0']
    ]
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxx')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setData(json)
        this.setState({
// CODE TO POPULATE THE TABLEDATA ABOVE
      });
        })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);
```

How can I populate this tableData with the relevant info coming back from my JSON call? An example of the JSON is below;

```
{
   "Pos": 1,
   "Team": "Cheshire Futsal Club Men",
   "Played": 0,
   "Won": 0,
   "Drawn": 0,
   "Lost": 0,
   "Goal Difference": 0,
   "Points": 0
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are guaranteed to get data in that format, and here I assume that the data is really an array of objects then you can simply convert each object to an array of values using

```
Object.values(row)
```

To create an array of arrays you can map over the original array like this:

```
 const formatted = data.map(row => Object.values(row))
```

Where data is the original data that you downloaded and formatted is an array of arrays in the form you need.